# Flummox and react-router example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm trying to get a test example of [flummox](http://acdlite.github.io/flummox/) and [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) working together (disclaimer: learning, so apologies for the dumb question).

I've found some neat example here https://github.com/olegsmetanin/react_react-router_flummox_example but it uses the deprecated `React.withContext` to boot up the app (from [index.jsx](https://github.com/olegsmetanin/react_react-router_flummox_example/blob/master/src/assets/js/apps/firstapp/index.jsx)):

```
  React.withContext(
    { flux },
    () => React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById(divid))
    );
```

Flummox now has a `<FluxComponent/>` that can be used to set the context but I can't seem to get it to work with a `react-router`.

If i'm doing this:

```
router.run((Handler, state) => {
    React.render(
            <FluxComponent flux={flux}>
                <Handler {...state}  />
            </FluxComponent>, 
            document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

My handler doesn't seem to receive flux in its context (and throws a warning in the console because it's missing).

Feels like I'm missing a vital piece of the puzzle here but can't find a concrete example of this (I can find old flummox/react/react-router example or new flummox/react but not using react-router).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using nested routes in your app?

Comment: @OlimSaidov Yes. I tried wrapping the nested routes with a `<FluxComponent>` but that throws a different kind of error (sorry, not in front of my dev machine so can't double check right now). I did try without using the nested routes though (just the top route) and the same thing happens.

Comment: Hmm, this looks good to me. It's basically identical to Flummox's doc app. https://github.com/acdlite/flummox/blob/master/docs/src/client/app.js#L21-L32 Are you sure the error's not coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @AndrewClark thanks - I hadn't thought about checking the source of your own docs for reference, good idea. I might study that a bit better and see what the issue is.

Comment: @AndrewClark In the flummox's doc source code, you don't seem to use it much though. Seems the flux object is mostly exposed via the `performRouteHandlerStaticMethod` call. Why is that??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not forget to define flux in contextTypes of your React component. You can catch context as a second argument in constructor.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.AppStore = context.flux.getStore('appStore');
    }
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  flux: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Some links from my [last example](http://oleg.smetan.in):

[React.render](https://github.com/olegsmetanin/olegsmetanin.github.io/blob/dev/src/assets/js/apps/blog/index.jsx)

[Component](https://github.com/olegsmetanin/olegsmetanin.github.io/blob/dev/src/assets/js/apps/blog/components/Instagram.jsx)

[Unit test of context](https://github.com/olegsmetanin/olegsmetanin.github.io/blob/dev/test/tests/Router.es7.jsx)

Comment: belated thanks for the help on this - I hadn't seen this more recent version. I'll experiment with it.

Comment: If I may ask.. AppHandler handles flux via `routerWillRunOnClient` (called from `Router.run` in the main index), rather than via context. I noticed @AndrewClark did the same with the flummox source. What's the advantage of doing this rather than using the context?

Comment: My code almost completely taken from @AndrewClark demo. routerWillRunOnClient is useful to fetch some data before component is created, so this method is static, look at this example https://github.com/olegsmetanin/olegsmetanin.github.io/blob/dev/src/assets/js/apps/blog/handlers/AppHandler.jsx